# RecyclerView in single fragment with Firebase data

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, android-recyclerview

**Application**

I am building an Android application wherein order for certain item will be taken from customers. These order can have 4 different status : `Pending`, `Confirmed`, `Completed` and `Cancelled`. I have written necessary firebase rule for the same.
My initial design was listing up all the orders in single activity, HomeActivity, and everything looked good. But then I decided to change the design to tabs and viewpager for each `status` of the order in the same `HomeActivity`. I am using one of the best library, **[smart tab layout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout)** to generate my views.

**Current Design**

I planned to keep one single `Fragment` and update the adapter of `recyclerview` accordingly.

*HomeActivity.java*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Global.replaceFragmentWithAnimation(new HomeTabFragment(), getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.frame_container);
}
```

`Global.replaceFragmentWithAnimation` is a static method which just replaces the fragment to necessary container.

*HomeTabFragment.java*

```
public class HomeTabFragment extends Fragment implements SmartTabLayout.TabProvider {
    public HomeTabFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_tab, container, false);
        final ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        final SmartTabLayout viewPagerTab = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab);
        viewPagerTab.setCustomTabView(this);
        FragmentPagerItems pages = new FragmentPagerItems(getContext());
        pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of("Pending", OrderListsFragment.class));
        pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of("Confirmed", OrderListsFragment.class));
        pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of("Cancelled", OrderListsFragment.class));
        pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of("Completed", OrderListsFragment.class));
        FragmentStatePagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentStatePagerItemAdapter(
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), pages);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        viewPagerTab.setViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPagerTab.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View createTabView(ViewGroup container, int position, PagerAdapter adapter) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext());
        View tab = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_icon_and_notification_mark, container, false);
        TextView txtTab = tab.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                txtTab.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.pending_tab_text));
                break;
            case 1:
                txtTab.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.confirmed_tab_text));
                break;
            case 2:
                txtTab.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.cancelled_tab_text));
                break;
            case 3:
                txtTab.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.completed_tab_text));
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid pos - " + position);
        }
        return tab;
    }
}
```

and finally this is my `OrderListFragment`

*OrderListFragment.java*

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_lists, container, false);
    recycler_view_order_list = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_order_list); //declared outside
    emptyView = view.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recycler_view_order_list.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recycler_view_order_list.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    loadOrders();
    return view;
}

public void loadOrders() {
    if (recycler_view_order_list != null) {
        recycler_view_order_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }
    final DatabaseReference orderTableRef = Global.getDatabase().getReference(Constants.ORDERS_TABLE);
    final DatabaseReference customerRef = Global.getDatabase().getReference(Constants.CUSTOMERS_TABLE);
    orderTableRef.keepSynced(true);
    customerRef.keepSynced(true);

    final Query orderList = orderTableRef.orderByChild("status").equalTo("Pending"); 
    //I hardcoded Pending value to make sure everything looks good.

    Global.adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Order, OrderItemHolder>(
            Order.class,
            R.layout.order_item_view,
            OrderItemHolder.class,
            orderList
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final OrderItemHolder viewHolder, final Order model, final int position) {
            if(model.getCustId()!=null) {
                customerRef.child(model.getCustId()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Customers customers = dataSnapshot.getValue(Customers.class);
                        //set Customer name

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                if ("Pending".equals(model.getStatus())) {
                     //Some UI updates for Pending
                }
                if ("Completed".equals(model.getStatus())) {
                    //Some UI updates for Pending
                }
                if ("Cancelled".equals(model.getStatus())) {
                    //Some UI updates for Pending
                }
                if ("Confirmed".equals(model.getStatus())) {
                    //Some UI updates for Pending
                }
            }
        }
    };

    orderTableRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren())
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver mObserver = new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            if (Global.adapter.getItemCount() == 0)
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
    Global.adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(mObserver);
    recycler_view_order_list.setAdapter(Global.adapter);
}
```

Very long code but I've shortened it as much as possible. I've couple of problems here.

- The data never gets displayed even though it is fetched in `orderList`. when debugged, it never hits `populateViewHolder` of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. When I did some research on this issue, All I found was to add `RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver` and register it to `Global.adapter` which I've already implemented. I am still confused as in why the data is not fetched. `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` for `orderTableRef` hits anyhow and `if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren())` condition within evaluates to `false` thus hiding `emptyView` message. Few suggestions from `GitHub` issue also stated to remove `recycler_view_order_list.setHasFixedSize(true);` but it did not help either.

  - How can I pass different order status for different tabs? I tried doing below within:

`HomeTabFragment.java`

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("orderType","Pending");
pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of("Pending", OrderListsFragment.class,bundle));
bundle.putString("orderType","Confirmed");
pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of("Confirmed", OrderListsFragment.class,bundle));
bundle.putString("orderType","Cancelled");
pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of("Cancelled",OrderListsFragment.class,bundle));
bundle.putString("orderType","Completed");
pages.add(FragmentPagerItem.of("Completed", OrderListsFragment.class,bundle));
```

Overriding `FragmentPagerItems`'s `add` method and passing budnle with different value for same `key` but then it ended up passing last value i.e. `Completed` during every initialization.

**Note -** `FragmentPagerItems` is an utility extension available with the tabs library used.

Could anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: You're passing the same Bundle instance to every FragmentPagerItem, so eventually they all have the same value set for `orderType`. Try using a new Bundle for every FragmentPagerItem.

Comment: Ok so everytime `new Bundle()` has to be created? Alright, I can try that.